# Users aren't being added to role - C# Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

Well, for some reason everytime I'm creating an user, it ain't being assigned with the role specified.

This is the part wherein I'm creating the user:

```
AppUser NUser = new AppUser()
            {
                UserName = registration.Username,
                FirstName = registration.FirstName,
                LastName = registration.LastName,
                Email = registration.Email,
                ZIPCode = registration.ZIPCode,
                EmailVerificationCode = RandomKey.AssignRandomKey(ref userManager),
                Courses = new List<CourseModel>()
            };

            userManager.Create(NUser, registration.Password);
            userManager.AddToRole(NUser.Id, registration.Role);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now, I need to get the users within an specific role, I'm doing it like so:

```
IdentityRole professorRole = roleManager.FindByName("Profesor");
List<AppUser> professors = userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == professorRole.Id)).ToList();
```

And I think that's right, if the users have the role within their collection, we take them.

But, while I was debugging, I realized that the users aren't created with a role, here's what I mean:
[image]

professorRole, which is IdentityRole, isn't supposed to have the lists of the users(IdentityUserRole) within that role? It says zero.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the value of `registration.Role` when you create `NUser`? Have you checked the DB table, is it saved there?

Comment: It's "Profesor" and yea, in the table IdentityRoles it's created. Also, in the table IdentityUserRole both UserId and RoleId are saved. How's that even possible?

Comment: Yo, wait a sec. Is it normal that AppUser_Id and IdentityRole_Id both are null? UserId and RoleId have their respective Ids, but I don't know about AppUser_Id and IdentityRole_Id...

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. I copied the content from UserId and RoleId into AppUser_Id and IdentityRole_Id respectively and debugged and now it works. Any idea why are those fields reamining null?